Bridge bidding question as responder with one point
Partner opened bidding with 1 heart.  Opening hand was 5 and 6 of spades, KQJ97 Hearts, K83 diamonds, AQ6 clubs (15 points).  I passed.  My hand was J83 spades, 862 hearts, 9654 diamonds, 10 7 5 clubs (1 point). Opponent bid one spade and partner doubled.  What should I have bid?

For about the last 80 years, your partner's double of 1S has been played by almost all good players as takeout.  Your partner knows you are weak (since you passed already) but still wants you to bid.
Keep in mind a very important fact about bridge scoring: going down a little in your contract is better than letting the opponents make their contract.  Your partner is not doubling necessarily because they think whatever you bid will make, but rather that it will just go down for little enough that it's better than letting opponents play 1S.
In this case, you should bid 2H (even playing 4 card majors).  That is likely to be your least bad spot.  Indeed, you go down 2 in 2H (for -100 or -200 depending on vulnerability) while opponents make 4 in 1S (for -410 or -710 depending on their vulnerability).  (Note, unless your opponents are known to be incompetent, your partner's double was a good bid, because, if you are as weak as you turned out to be, competent opponents will bid to 4S (a game) in the absence of a double anyway, and if you are a bit stronger, 2H might have been a good contract.)

It's worth noting partner should have opened 1NT on that balanced hand, so isnt totally innocent! Thier (Takeout) double suggests a hand shape of 6H 3D 3C 1S so having 3 cards in the 2 unbid suits and shortage in opponents suit. - So opener is asking you to either bid one of the 3 card suits or support Hearts. In your case, raise Hearts irrespective of your strength.

@postrationalist - not everyone belongs to the church of opening 1N on all hands with a 5 card major in range, nor does everyone belong to the church of strong NTs.

Learn not the ways of the heathen, For the wages of sin are ... lower scores! - If we walk in the light, we have fellowship one with other  :)

@postrationalist: I'm playing Precision with 10-12 NT at the moment..  I open 1H on xx Qxxxx Axx Axx but 1N on Qx Axxxx Qxx Qxx

So to clarify, the bidding was 1H - pass - pass - 1S - double - all pass? What was the vulnerability, any prior agreements?
Normally in the absence of an agreement to the contrary, a double of 1 of a suit is takeout, 1NT for penalties, so if the above is correct then you can't pass 1Sx with that hand, that would signal a hand willing and able to defeat 1S. Partner must know you have a really poor hand from your first pass, which makes it somewhat surprising that he's doubled for takeout. I play 5 card majors with partner and in this hole, I'd bid 2H (knowing at least we have eight trumps) as the least encouraging bid and hope partner understood we couldn't possibly have the majority of the strength.
